# Persisting Session to DB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

My architect is wondering why we need to persist each user's session to the DB instead of just using cookies.  I have never seen anyone use just cookies.

Usually I hold the Session Id in a cookie then use it to perform CRUDS on the session record keyed off the ID.

I mean I don't see how you can do session state without in proc.  I've always done session state via a custom table holding routine fields like IsLoggedIn, IsClosed, IsNew, IPAddress, Browser, and so on.

Has anyone done session state on an e-commerce site without persisting it in a DB?

**UPDATED**

So here is kinda how we did things at another place I worked for an e-commerce site that got 500+ page hits a month:

```
public USession CreateNewSession(int userID)
{
    string ipAddress = GetCurrentRequestIPAddress(context.Request);

    USession newSession = USession.NewSession();
    newSession.IpAddress = ipAddress;
    newSession.UserID = customerID;
    newSession.Browser = context.Request.UserAgent ?? string.Empty;

    if (context.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
    newSession.Referer = context.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
    else
    newSession.Referer = string.Empty;

    InsertSession(newSession);

    return newSession;
}



public USession CreateNewSession(int userID)
{
    string ipAddress = GetCurrentRequestIPAddress(context.Request);

    USession newSession = USession.NewSession();
    newSession.IpAddress = ipAddress;
    newSession.UserID = customerID;
    newSession.Browser = context.Request.UserAgent ?? string.Empty;

    if (context.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
         newSession.Referer = context.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
    else
         newSession.Referer = string.Empty;

    InsertSession(newSession);

    return newSession;
}



public USession GetSession()
{
    // existing sessionId this session?
    HttpCookie cookie = context.Request.Cookies["usessionId"];

    if (cookie == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Value))
    session = CreateNewSession(0);
    else
    {
        string sessionID = cookie.Value;

        session = GetSession(sessionID);

        if (session == null) 
            session = CreateNewSession(0);
        else if (session.IsClosed > 0) 
            session = CreateNewSession(session.UserID);
    }

    if (session.LastAccessed < DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1)) session.LoggedIn = false;

    if (session.LastDestination.Equals("lesson"))
        session.LastDestPageDestinationID = ContextValue(context, "lessonid");
    else
        session.LastDestPageDestinationID = 0;

    if (session.IsNew) session.FirstDestination = session.LastDestination;

    SaveSession();

    return session;
}



private void SaveSession()
{
    session.LastAccess = DateTime.Now;
    session.LastDest = string.Empty;

    db.UpdateSession(session);

    if (!cookieIsSet)
    {
        // add a session cookie for this current session
        HttpCookie cookie = CreateSessionCookie("usessionId", session.SessionID, 365);

        if (session.LastDest.Equals("logout", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            cookie.Value = string.Empty;

        if (session.LastDest.Equals("lessonOrder")) return;

        context.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
    }
}


internal void UpdateSession(USession s)
{
    using (ourConnection conn = CreateConnection("UpdateSession"))
    {
        conn.CommandText = @"update csession set
            closed = @closed,
            userID = @customerID,
            lastAccess = @lastAccess,
            lastDestination = @lastDest,
                        orderId = @OrderId,
            IsloggedIn = @isLoggedIn;

        conn.AddParam("@id", s.Id);
        conn.AddParam("@closed", s.Closed);
        conn.AddParam("@userID", s.UserID);
        conn.AddParam("@lastAccess", s.LastAccess);
        conn.AddParam("@firstDestination", s.FirstDestination);
        conn.AddParam("@lastDestination", s.LastDestination);
        conn.AddParam("@isLoggedIn", s.IsLoggedIn);
        conn.AddParam("@orderID", s.OrderID);

        try
        {
            conn.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogException(ex);
        }
    }
}


public HttpCookie CreateSessionCookie(string cookieValue, string uSessionID, double daysTillExpiration)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("usessionid", uSessionID);
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(daysTillExpiration);
    cookie.Path = "/";

    return cookie;
}
```

So we'd work with the USession custom object in memory throughout our code for checking for loggedIn, to force close their session, and all sorts of stuff based on their current session.

Also in our Application_Error in global.asax we would log the current sessionId for tracking purposes on error.

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["usessionid"];
if (cookie != null)
{
    logger.Variables = "<b>uSessionID:</b> " + cookie.Value;

    if (cookie.Value.Length > 0)
        logger.USessionID = GetUSessionID(cookie.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The ASP.NET session has 3 possible states:

- Off (my preferred) - don't use any session at all
- InProc - the session is stored in the memory of the web server. Fast, but not convinient if you are running in a web farm because each node of the web farm will have a different copy of the session and you might get conflicts.
- Out-of-Proc - the session is stored in memory of a specially dedicated server running the ASP.NET Session state Windows service. Good for webfarms scenarios but not reliable enough as the session is still persisted in the memory of some server which might not survive crashes.
- SQL Server - the session is persisted in SQL server. Very reliable and suitable for web farms. Problem is with performance. It will be slower than the previous modes as the session is now persisted in the database.

The 3 modes are covered in depth in the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx).

The mode you choose is configured in web.config and it is completely transparent to your code in which you simply use the `Session["someKey"]` to work with the session, it's just the underlying storage mechanism that differs.

Comment: Yea so you can't just base session on cookies.  I have worked on e-commerce sites who got 500,000 page views in a month with no performance issue using a custom Session Table and using that to check session status or create a new session record for a user.

Comment: Why would you have session completely off?  You have to check authentication, etc. and pull stuff like their IPAddress, Referer for logging, etc. amongst many other things such as determining if the session has expired or explicitly close the session under certain circumstances, etc.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, no matter which of the 3 persistent modes you choose, the session is by default tracked by cookies (in the 3 modes).

Comment: Strange, it's weird then why would we have had a session table at a previous job?  I saw how it worked and didn't question it.  We used a cookie to store the sessionId and then held session data in the HttpContext.

Comment: As far as why I would turn session off, I think you have some misunderstandings about what a *session* is. You seem to be confusing the ASP.NET session and the forms authentication provider which are 2 completely different things. The ASP.NET session is what I covered in my answer. The Forms authentication is an authentication mechanism that allows you to track authenticated users using cookies. The user id is stored in an encrypted cookie and sent along each request allowing the server to track which is the authenticated user. I have no idea about what *session table* you are talking about.

Comment: An ASP.NET session is by default tracked by cookies but that's configurable - you could use hidden fields or query string parameters - I think in ASP.NET MVC you could use only cookies though, the other modes refer to classic WebForms. So back to the point - I turn ASP.NET Session off in my web.config file as I never need it. I design my applications in a RESTful manner. I store any information I need in my backed or use caching to minimize hits on it. And to track authenticated user I use the built-in Forms Authentication which relies on cookies by default.

Comment: The session data table was a custom table of ours in SQL Server which we inserted a record for every unique session.  That table had fields like uSessionId (unique session Id) that represented the session's Id, CustomerId, IPAddress, lastAccess, LoggedIn, LastDestination, CartItems, etc.

Comment: so we held the user's uSessionId encrypted in a custom cookie used as their unique uSessionId. We simply used the cookie to get that at Id any time client side. We put an expiration on the cookie. Now server-side we used that uSessionId value from their cookie to go grab their session data from the DB if our custom Session Object was no longer in memory to work with that we had created when they first initiated their session.  We work with the custom session object in memory throughout our server-side code to check stuff like IsLoggedIn, LastDestination, Closed (is their session closed), etc.

Comment: When a customer logs in, we call         public bool Login(string email, string password)
        {
            customer = db.GetCustomer(email, password);
            if (customer == null)
                return false;

            db.Login(session.Id, customer.Id);
            session.CustomerID = customer.Id;
            session.LoggedIn = true;
            return true;
        }

Comment: Logout was         public void Logout()
        {
            this.customer = null;
            this.session.LoggedIn = false;
            this.session.CustomerID = 0;

            db.Logout(session.Id);
        }

Comment: I added the type of code I worked with at another large e-commerce site.  See the original post update now.

Comment: we had no performance issues with InProc via SQL Server and again we had up to 500,000 hits a month and this site was tested for much over that range and could handle it with no problem